# Opencart кастомное поле в админке

Tags: php, opencart, server-side-rendering

добавил доп. поле "описание внизу" в категорию в админке. Реализовал сохранение данных в базу данных( добавил доп. поле в таблицу category). Теперь в controller'е вывожу значение этого поля для текущей категории. Пример функции в Model:

```
   public function getCustomField($field,$catid){
         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ".$field." FROM " . DB_PREFIX . 
    "category WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$catid . "'");
         return $query->row['bottom_text'];
    }
```

Вызываю в controller каталога:

```
  $data['bottext'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCustomField('bottom_text',$category_id);
```

Вывожу во view каталога :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе получаю кусок неотрендеренного html кода, который сохранял в админке пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит на сайте :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как правильно вывести код? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ сам, достаточно было прописать
html_entity_decode($this->model_catalog_category->getCustomField('bottom_text',$category_id), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');